# Ограничение камеры по оси X

Tags: unity3d

Есть простой кусок кода:

```
float x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
float y = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
 
var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
angles.y += x; 
angles.x += y;
transform.eulerAngles = angles;
```

Однако если посмотреть прямо вверх, а потом вниз, то камера игрока может перевернутся. Пытался писать ограничения, но не понимаю природу поворотов. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: псевдокод ```angles.x += y; if angles.x>90deg then angles.x=90deg;```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, не работает, пробовал

Comment: Так бывает, особенно если пропустить указание величин которые приведены сразу в примере :) 90deg - это 90 градусов, если мне память не изменяет стандартные единицы - радианы. Т.е. вам нужно заменить 90 градусов на столько же но радиан(90 это если мне память не изменяет половина от пи) так же вам нужно вторую границу указывать, плюс не понятно в какую сторону вращение идет(0-180, 90-270, 180-360, ....) мне не известно где у вас горизонт(в нуле или нет...)